# How To Fix Incorrect Name In Mod Glitch (Minecraft Bedrock)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

so I am creating an addon, but my blocks and items all the sudden are displaying the wrong names (Example: title.sepular_ore.name) I opened the en_US.lang file, and this is what I found:

```
"tile.pa:sepular_ore.name=Sepular Ore\nitem.pa:sepular_ingot.name=Sepular Ingot\nitem.pa:sepular_sword.name=Sepular Sword\nitem.pa:sepular_axe.name=Sepular Axe\nitem.pa:sepular_pickaxe.name=Sepular Pickaxe\nitem.pa:sepular_shovel.name=Sepular Shovel\nitem.pa:sepular_hoe.name=Sepular Hoe\ntile.pa:sepular_block.name=Sepular Block\nitem.pa:sepulant_tube.name=Sepulant Tube\nitem.pa:crushed_sepulant.name=Crushed Sepulant\ntile.pa:sepular_block_cracked.name=Cracked Sepular Block\nitem.pa:sepular_guard_suit.name=Sepular Guard Suit\nitem.pa:sepular_pearl.name=Sepular Pearl\ntile.pa:chiseled_sepular_block.name=Sepular Chiseled Block\ntile.pa:smooth_sepular_block.name=Smooth Sepular\nitem.spawn_egg.entity.pa:sepular_tnt.name=Sepular TNT\nentity.pa:sepular_tnt.name=Sepular TNT\ntile.pa:chiseled_sepular_slab.name=Chiseled Sepular Slab\ntile.pa:sepular_slab_cracked.name=Cracked Sepular Slab\ntile.pa:smooth_sepular_slab.name=Smooth Sepular Slab\ntile.pa:sepular_slab.name=Sepular Slab\ntile.pa:sepular_stairs.name=Sepular Stairs\ntile.pa:chiseled_sepular_stairs.name=Chiseled Sepular Stairs\ntile.pa:smooth_sepular_stairs.name=Smooth Sepular Stairs\ntile.pa:sepular_stairs_cracked.name=Cracked Sepular Stairs\ntile.pa:light_green_stained_glass.name=Sepulant Stained Glass\ntile.pa:sedimentary.name=Sedimentary\nitem.pa:sepular_nugget.name=Sepular Nugget\ntile.pa:sepular_flower.name=of the Sepular\ntile.pa:polished_sedimentary.name=Polished Sedimentary\ntile.pa:brick_sedimentary.name=Sedimentary Brick\ntile.pa:sedimentary_slab.name=Sedimentary Slab\ntile.pa:sedimentary_stairs.name=Sedimentary Stairs\ntile.pa:polished_sedimentary_slab.name=Polished Sedimentary Slab\ntile.pa:polished_sedimentary_stairs.name=Polised Sedimentary Stairs\ntile.pa:sedimentary_brick_slab.name=Sedimentary Brick Slab\ntile.pa:sedimentary_brick_stairs.name=Sedimentary Brick Stairs\ntile.pa:smooth_sepular_block_dyed.name=Dyed Smooth Sepular Block\ntile.pa:smooth_sepular_slab_dyed.name=Dyed Smooth Sepular Slab\ntile.pa:smooth_sepular_stairs_dyed.name=Dyed Smooth Sepular Stairs\nitem.spawn_egg.entity.pa:sepular_guard.name=Spawn Sepular Guard\nentity.pa:sepular_guard.name=Sepular Guard\nitem.spawn_egg.entity.pa:op_entity.name=Spawn OP Entity\nentity.pa:op_entity.name=OP Entity\nitem.spawn_egg.entity.pa:epic_trader.name=Spawn Epic Trader\nentity.pa:epic_trader.name=Epic Trader\nitem.spawn_egg.entity.pa:buddy.name=Spawn Buddy\nentity.pa:buddy.name=Buddy\nitem.pa:sepular_flower_seed.name=Seed of the Sepular\nitem.pa:sepular_flower_seed=Seed of the Sepular\n##
```

Sorry if that is messy. I looked up how to fix it but nothing came up for bedrock:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The issue is `\n` is literally written. Replace all instances of `\n` with a line break (<kbd>Enter</kbd> key) and it should work.

## Why did this happen? (Speculation)

It looks like this was automated with some sort of program and some sort of error was made (accidentally escaping the backslash, accidentally using a verbatim string, etc.) which made what normally signifies a new line (`\n` usually means line break in almost every programming language) literally just saying backslash n.